# Выделение памяти под массив объектов

Tags: c++, объекты, память

Есть класс A, у которого есть единственный конструктор, который принимает 2 аргумента. Как мне выделить память через new для n объектов, используя скобочную нотацию?

Comment: то есть, хочется получить массив объектов, но назвать это массивом не хочется?

Comment: A* a = new A[n];
Вот вы мне может скажите, что мне делать, если у меня нет дефолтного конструктора?

Comment: использовать placement new

Answer (score 0):

Никак.
Используйте `std::vector`.

Comment: А разве нельзя с const_cast'ами помудрить там?